# Decoding multi-level JSON into structs in iOS with Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, multi-level, decodable, jsondecoder

I'm trying to decode my data into structs. Here is an example of one of my data structure as JSON:

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "owner": "bcd",
    "fallbackLanguage": "tr",
    "localizedValues": {
        "en": {
            "description": "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet"
        },
        "de": {
            "description": "Sed Do Eiusmod Tempor Incididunt"
        },
        "tr": {
            "description": "Consectetur Adipisicing Elit"
        }
    }
}
```

And struct for this JSON object is:

```
struct X {
  let name: String
  let owner: String
  let fallbackLanguage: String

  let description: String
}
```

Decoding `name`, `owner` and `fallbackLanguage` is not a problem and already done. Here is the current `CodingKey` and `init(from:)`

```
struct CodingKeys: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    init?(stringValue: String) {
      self.stringValue = stringValue
    }

    var intValue: Int?
    init?(intValue: Int) {
      self.intValue = intValue
      self.stringValue = "\(intValue)"

    }

    static func makeKey(name: String) -> CodingKeys {
      return CodingKeys.init(stringValue: name)!
    }
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    owner = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.makeKey(name: "owner"))
    name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.makeKey(name: "name"))
    fallbackLanguage = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.makeKey(name: "fallbackLanguage"))

    // FIXME: decode localizedValues into `description`
}
```

The problem is decoding `description`, since it's hold in a multi-level dictionary, and it's value will change due to device locale.

In this example, if device locale is not `en`, `de` or `tr`, it will fallback to `tr` since fallbackLanguage is `tr`.

Any help and suggestions would be great. Thank you.

**Note**: I included [this gist](https://gist.github.com/inamiy/374cdaa09ef3c7eff0f88fc8ef315463) by [inamiy](https://gist.github.com/inamiy) to encode / decode dictionaries and arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @AndyObusek, I've learned that there are `nestedContainers`.

Here is the final solution for my problem:

```
    // get localizedValues as nested container
    let localizedValues = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: CodingKeys.makeKey(name: "localizedValues")!)

    var localizations: KeyedDecodingContainer<CodingKeys>

    // if device locale identifier exists in the localizedValues container as a key get it as nested container, else get for fallbackLanguage.

    if localizedValues.contains(CodingKeysmakeKey(name: Locale.current.identifier)!) {
      localizations = try localizedValues.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: CodingKeys.makeKey(name: Locale.current.identifier))
    } else {
      localizations = try localizedValues.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: CodingKeys.makeKey(name: fallbackLanguage))
    }

    // set description
    description = try localizations.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.makeKey(name: "description"))
```

EDIT:

My data is a **Cloud Firestore** data, and I've found a great POD created by *alickbass* for encoding and decoding data for/from Firebase named [CodableFirebase](https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase) which is the simplest and best solution around if you use Firebase Database or Cloud Firestore

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to create a struct for `localizedValues` and decode the value into a dictionary. Then get the current `fallbackLanguage` and get the corresponding description from the dictionary. Custom `CodingKeys` and initializer is not needed.

```
let jsonString = """
{    "name": "abc",
    "owner": "bcd",
    "fallbackLanguage": "tr",
    "localizedValues": {
        "en": { "description": "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet"},
        "de": { "description": "Sed Do Eiusmod Tempor Incididunt"},
        "tr": { "description": "Consectetur Adipisicing Elit"}
    }
}
"""
```

---

```
struct X : Decodable {
    let name: String
    let owner: String
    let fallbackLanguage: String

    let localizedValues: [String:LocalizedValue]
}

struct LocalizedValue : Decodable {
    let description : String
}

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(X.self, from: data)
    let fallBackLanguage = result.fallbackLanguage
    let fallBackLanguageDescription = result.localizedValues[fallBackLanguage]?.description
    print(fallBackLanguageDescription)

} catch { print(error)}
```

Comment: I've thought about that. But `localizedValues` are shared across my all structs and their content vary. One has only `description`, one has `name` too, one does not have `description` etc. So I decided not to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [this extension](https://github.com/3D4Medical/glTFSceneKit/blob/master/Sources/glTFSceneKit/GLTF/JSONCodingKeys.swift) for encoding and decoding `Array<Any>` and `Dictionary<String: Any>`

Swift 4:

```
struct X: Decodable {

    let name: String?
    let owner: String?
    let fallbackLanguage: String?
    let localizedValues: Dictionary<String, Any>?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, owner, fallbackLanguage, localizedValues
    }
}
```

Comment: It's much like the extension that I use. Thank you.

Comment: @LLoyd Keijzer Whats name of extension? I see 404 on the link you mentioned https://github.com/3D4Medical/glTFSceneKit/blob/master/Sources/gltf_scenekit/GLTF/JSONCodingKeys.swift

Comment: @Naren You can find it here https://github.com/3D4Medical/glTFSceneKit/blob/master/Sources/glTFSceneKit/GLTF/JSONCodingKeys.swift

Answer (score 0):

With your json you can create following struct

```
struct LocalizedJSONObject: Codable {
    let name, owner, fallbackLanguage: String?
    let localizedValues: LocalizedValues?
}

struct LocalizedValues: Codable {
    let en, de, tr: De?
}

struct De: Codable {
    let description: String?
}

// MARK: Convenience initializers

extension LocalizedJSONObject {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(LocalizedJSONObject.self, from: data)
    }

    init(_ json: String, using encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws {
        guard let data = json.data(using: encoding) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "JSONDecoding", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
        }
        try self.init(data: data)
    }

    init(fromURL url: URL) throws {
        try self.init(data: try Data(contentsOf: url))
    }

    func jsonData() throws -> Data {
        return try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }

    func jsonString(encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws -> String? {
        return String(data: try self.jsonData(), encoding: encoding)
    }
}

extension LocalizedValues {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(LocalizedValues.self, from: data)
    }

    init(_ json: String, using encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws {
        guard let data = json.data(using: encoding) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "JSONDecoding", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
        }
        try self.init(data: data)
    }

    init(fromURL url: URL) throws {
        try self.init(data: try Data(contentsOf: url))
    }

    func jsonData() throws -> Data {
        return try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }

    func jsonString(encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws -> String? {
        return String(data: try self.jsonData(), encoding: encoding)
    }
}

extension De {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(De.self, from: data)
    }

    init(_ json: String, using encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws {
        guard let data = json.data(using: encoding) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "JSONDecoding", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
        }
        try self.init(data: data)
    }

    init(fromURL url: URL) throws {
        try self.init(data: try Data(contentsOf: url))
    }

    func jsonData() throws -> Data {
        return try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }

    func jsonString(encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws -> String? {
        return String(data: try self.jsonData(), encoding: encoding)
    }
}
```

And use like this

```
let localizedJSONObject = try LocalizedJSONObject(json)
```

Comment: I've already implemented convenience initializers but did not add to this question, since they are irrelevant to the real question. And about the `LocalizedValues` struct, I've already thought about that. But localizedValues are shared across my all structs and their content vary. One has only description, one has name too, one does not have description etc. So I decided not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not tight on a schedule, give this library a shot: [Swifty Json](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

It has a few built in methods that might abstract your needs, such as casting a nested-dictionary Json object into an NSDictionary, where you can extract values out and apply control flow over them to build a logic around.

Comment: SwiftyJSON is a great library but as JSON parser it became obsolete after introducing native JSON decoding in Swift 4 and you are discouraged from using `NSDictionary` in Swift at all.

Comment: Thank you, Mert. I will take a look at that but I have to consider what @vadian said too.